# How can a substring from a varchar variable be null?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Primarily as an SQL Server user I was suprised that in Oracle this syntax is valid:

```
select var
from table
where substr(var, 2, 1) is null
```

How can a subsrting from varchar string variable be `null`? In SQL Server this would never be true(?).

```
select var
from table
where substring(var, 2, 1) is null
```

Comment: Never say never. If var is null then the result of the SUBSTRING will be null, even in SQL Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In many cases in Oracle, [the empty string is actually NULL](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/empty_null.php).

If you substr() outside the range of your in-string, SQL server returns the empty string, while Oracle returns NULL (its equivalent to the empty string).

Comment: One of Oracle's little quirks, I'm afraid.

Comment: I didn't know that ! Surprising, isn't it ?

Comment: Don't even go there ;-) Google on 'empty string null oracle' and a whole new world opens for you. It's the way oracle choose to handle emprty strings before ANSI existed.

Comment: If a database product vendor chose to store all the data as text internally, then the empty string could easily be used as a way of representing NULL. But for string data type that would mean that NULLs and empty strings would be indistinguishable. I wonder if that's how the guys in Oracle have chosen to store data in *their* product.

Answer (score 1):

In general, `null` means absence of value.

```
select  substr ('abcd',2, 1) from dual;
-- result: 'b'

select  substr ('a',2, 1) from dual;
-- empty, because there is nothing at second position on string 'a';

select decode(substr('a',2,1),null, 'yes, is null') from dual;
-- result: 'yes, is null'


select decode('', null, 'yes, is null') from dual;
-- result: 'yes, is null'
```

Update:
It is clear a choice of implementation. 
In most languages, for example in Java, Strings are placed in a memory area, and, for programmer, string variables are references to the area in the memory. So, an empty string is a reference to an area of length 0, but the reference isn't null. So, null is a different thing(no reference) and I think like you: it is better.

Comment: I'm a bit confused beceause I think that in database theory null and empty string is totally different thing. Null is nothing and empty string is an empty string!

Comment: empty number is null, there is no doubt of that :) The problem comes for string...

Comment: I come from the Oracle world so I don't (want to) see what the problem is with 'empty string' = null. Then they start about esotheric things like 'we want to see if the field has been touched' ;-)

Comment: @RobertMerkwürdigeliebe it would be nice to have that ;) (I'm sure we can live with this "empty string" nullness.) However, i'd like to update my answer with some things that come as benefits from this implementation, like space saving, or others, but I don't have time at hand...